# Binding toggle comment to <C-/>

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, vimscript, plugin-nerdcommenter

I installed [NERDCommenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter) plugin and its default bindings unfortunately conflict with my own. For instance I use `<Leader>-c` and `<Leader>-v` to emulate `CTRL-c` and `CTRL-v`. And since IDEs usually use `CTRL-/` to toggle comments I'd like to preserve this behavior.

I tried the following in my `vimrc`:

```
let g:NERDCommenterToggle = "<C-/>"
```

But when reloading the `vimrc` the old mapping `<Leader>c<Space>` is still in effect; the `<C-/>` mapping has no effect.

Is there a way to cancel all the default bindings introduced by `NERDCommenter` and bind only `g:NERDCommenterToggle` to `C-/`?

Comment: notice that c-/ is like ESC and can make the computer beep.

Answer (score 4):

I'm just going by the help doc in github but it appears that `'NERDCreateDefaultMappings'` does exactly what you want for the first part, ie. toggle on/off all mappings (bindings)...

> If set to 0, none of the default mappings will be created.

Then you can manually bind to your heart's content. The help for `NERDCommenterMappings` has a bit of advice for that:

> To change a mapping just map another key combo to the internal  mapping. For example, to remap the |NERDCommenterComment| mapping to ",omg" you would put this line in your vimrc:

```
map ,omg <plug>NERDCommenterComment
```

**Update:** If you need more help let's look at how the default for `NERDCommenterToggle` is constructed. It should be clear now that we don't override like a normal variable (`:let x = y`) but rather we need to define a mapping. The relevant bits responsible for defining the default mapping...

```
call s:CreateMaps('nx', 'Toggle', 'Toggle', 'c<space>')
```

Signature of `CreateMaps`:

```
function! s:CreateMaps(modes, target, desc, combo)
```

Actual map definition where `modes` is split and iterated over such that `mode` has each value, `n` and `x`, in turn...

```
execute mode . 'map <leader>' . a:combo . ' ' . plug
```

Where `plug` is

```
let plug = '<plug>NERDCommenter' . a:target
```

So that translates to

```
nmap <leader>c<space> <plug>NERDCommenterToggle
xmap <leader>c<space> <plug>NERDCommenterToggle
```

So you want

```
nmap <C-/> <plug>NERDCommenterToggle
xmap <C-/> <plug>NERDCommenterToggle
```

You may not need the `xmap` version.

(Don't forget you need to set `NERDCreateDefaultMappings` to 0, too.)